# sizeof() on custom library constructor returns wrong result

Tags: library, array

I made a custom library (let's call it `DigitalOutput.h`) to learn a bit about librairies and to simplify my work. Here is the basic constructor in the *.h* file:

```
DigitalOutput(uint8_t pin);
```

Here is the code in the *.cpp* file :

```
DigitalOutput::DigitalOutput(uint8_t pin)
{
    _pin    = pin;
    _status = LOW;
    pinMode(pin, OUTPUT);
}
```

So very simple stuff. Now, in my program, I call the function the usual way:

```
DigitalOutput LED(7); // pin #7 will be configured 
                      // as an output pin to control the LED
```

Now the issue comes when I create an array and then use the `sizeof()` function.
Here is the code from my program (using an Arduino Mega):

```
DigitalOutput   LED_array[] = {22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,
                               30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37};
```

So, the array contains **16** elements. But when I do for instance...

```
#define         LED_NUMBER    sizeof(LED_array)
//...
void setup(){
    //...
    Serial.println(sizeof(LED_array));
    Serial.println(LE_NUMBER);
}
```

...I get **160** as a result in both cases instead of **16**...

So I end up doing a weird `#define LED_NUMBER sizeof(LED_array) / 10` in order to get the proper result which is then used throughout the program. Any idea of why this isn't working right?

Comment: Please give a full working example that we can test ourself. Then we will tell you why a single object uses 10 bytes. Despite the compiler optimizations, I think that when the same object is declared more than once, that the size will be the same for every object.

Comment: As you already have the answer, I'll just mention a macro to address this very issue, `#define countof(a) (sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]))`, where `countof(LED_Array)` evaluates to the number of members in the array, not to its memory size. I keep this definition in an 'h' file on my local system (named, oddly enough, `local.h`!) with other simple-but-useful tools I need on occasion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is working perfectly correctly.

`sizeof` doesn't return the number of elements in an array, it returns *the number of bytes the array takes up*. Since each entry in your array is an instance of your DigitalOutput class, the size is the number of elements multiplied by the size of the class - in this case 10 bytes.

To get the number of elements you must divide the number of bytes by the size of one element:

```
int numEles = sizeof(LED_array) / sizeof(DigitalOutput);
```

or

```
int numEles = sizeof(LED_array) / sizeof(LED_array[0]);
```

Comment: Well thanks to you all. This was the problem, I did not understand `sizeof()` well enough and read its definition in the Arduino documentations without really understanding what it was doing. I went back to it with your comments and now I'm getting it. Thanks for your help guys.

Comment: Note that the first is more robust (using sizeof(DigitalOutput)), in case you ever make LED_array dynamic and it has zero elements.

Comment: If you make the array dynamic you won't be using `sizeof`. That will just return the size of the pointer (2 or 4 depending on architecture) regardless of the size of the array. `sizeof` is a compile-time command not a library function.

Comment: Thanks Michel, I actually went with `sizeof(DigitalOutput)`but without foreseeing the issues you were mentioning. Good to know! Thanks Majenko, that's some good input I actually totally assumed it was a function.

Comment: Most people do. The C++ reference actually lists it as an *operator* - that is, in the same class as `+`, `/`, etc.

Comment: Indeed. By the way, does it mean I shouldn't use `sizeof` during runtime and only use it for compile-time operations? Will it cause unexpected errors? Or, as it is listed as an _operator_, will it be fine?

Comment: It will be replaced at compile time with the size of whatever you specify. Since sizes of static things never change at runtime what you ask makes no sense.

Comment: @Majenko ... I meant more like the (amount of bytes used by the dynamic array) / sizeof(DigitalOutput ) ... returning 2 or 4 does not really give helpful information :-)

Answer (score 0):

You are checking the size of the object (DigitalOutput).
This object contains:

- _pin
- _status

And this probably results in 10 bytes per object, times 16 objects = 160 bytes.

So you are not creating an (unsigned byte) array which is 16 bytes.